# sort data in doc elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have a result of elascticsearch(6.8) query like this:

```
{
'popular':10,   
'sales' : 
   [
    'price' : 2, 
   ' price' : 1
   ]
},
 {'popular' :5,
 'sales' : 
   ['price' : 4, 
   'price' : 3]}
}

it sort by popular desc/
And I want to sort prices in sale asc.
```

I used sort by popular desc and salas.price asc, but in not that result for me

```
Good result for me 
{
'popular':10,   
'sales' : 
   [
    'price' : 1, 
   ' price' : 2
   ]
},
 {'popular' :5,
 'sales' : 
   ['price' : 3, 
   'price' : 4]}
}

Can I do it's in elasticsearch?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can't do this. Because elastic send  docs, and can sort docs, not data in doc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).